# Generating PDF with TOC using pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have an html file I need to convert to a PDF. Here's my code:

```
import pdfkit

#Define path to wkhtmltopdf.exe
path_to_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'

#Define path to HTML file
path_to_file = "database-pdf.html"

#Define path to css file
css_path = "print.css"

#Point pdfkit configuration to wkhtmltopdf.exe
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_to_wkhtmltopdf)

cover = "cover.html"

toc = {
    "xsl-style-sheet": "toc.xsl"
}

options = {
        "enable-local-file-access": None,
        "page-height": "297mm",
        "page-width": "210mm",
}

#Convert HTML file to PDF
pdfkit.from_file(path_to_file, css=css_path,  output_path='database.pdf', configuration=config, options=options, toc=toc, cover=cover, cover_first=True )
```

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (I know there was an issue with the previous version, but this is supposedly fine)

The toc.xsl is just the basic toc I dumped from wkhtmltopdf.

When I generate the PDF, only a blank page displays instead of the TOC.

I tried to generate PDF directly with the wkhtmltopdf cli command, using toc option, which worked, but I had other problems with that.

I also tried to run the script with the verbose flag, here's what I get. I tried to find out what the errors meant, but couldn't.

```
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
Counting pages (2/6)
Error XTSE0010 in file:///C:/Program%20Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe, at line 1, column 38: Parse error: Encountered incorrectly encoded content.
Loading TOC (3/6)
Error XTSE0010 in file:///C:/Program%20Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe, at line 1, column 38: Parse error: Encountered incorrectly encoded content.
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Done
Error: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the table of content then pass it like this,

```
toc = {
    "toc-header-text": "TOC title",
}
```

Make sure the titles are written using `h1...h6` tags